# How to build LLVM (clang, lld, mlir) (release/16.x)?

Tags: cmake, build, clang, llvm, ninja

First things first; the versions of various tools that I am using:

```bash
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
ld: 2.34
gold: GNU gold (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu 2.34) 1.16
gcc/g++: 9.4.0
cmake: 3.26.0
ninja: 1.10.0
```

Some details about hardware configurations:

```bash
memory: 16 GiB
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
```

I have cloned the `release/16.x` branch from **llvm-project** repository. After creating the build directory and moving under it, I am using the following command:

```bash
user@system:~/llvm-project/build$ cmake -G "Ninja" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="lld;clang" -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="RISCV" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On -DLLVM_PARALLEL_COMPILE_JOBS=1 -DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=1 ../llvm

user@system:~/llvm-project/build$ ninja -j 1
```

The build of *llvm* itself proceeds successfully. However, when the linking process for **bin/clang-16** begins, the system hangs (apparently uses too much memory), and after sometime I get the following message (snippet re-generated *after* core llvm build completed):

```bash
[0/613] Linking CXX executable bin/clang-16
FAILED: bin/clang-16
: && /usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -fno-semantic-interposition -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=date-time -Wall -Wextra
-Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long
-Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-redundant-move -Wno-pessimizing-move
-Wno-noexcept-type ...
...
...
... lib/libLLVMDemangle.a -lrt -ldl -lpthread -lm && :
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [killed]
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

(*I have skipped some lines in between!*)

Any help is welcome.

**P.S.**: Since I will be playing around with the source code of llvm and clang, I DO NOT want a `release` build. I think the real problem is static linking, which my computer is not able to handle. I went through the answer to [Not able to build LLVM from its source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65637234), but am unable to ascertain where and how to set the flags. Further, the answer to [Fatal Error building the llvm source code in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44808601/14739759) also suggests a cmake flag. What should be the correct mixture of flags?

Comment: I build LLVM with clang even on VM Ubuntu with 4GB RAM. Try to install clang-14 and use it for building LLVM.

Comment: I need to modify clang as well as part of my experiment, which is why I need to build it from source.

Comment: Please read carefully my comment. Build LLVM with clang, not use it.

Comment: will clang help with the linking process? clang is compiler driver, right? what linker will it use in background? ld? lld? gold? how do we set that?

Comment: There have been many questions about this before. So many that the LLVM build documentation answers it: LLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=2 or even =1.

Comment: @arnt, merely setting parallel jobs was not sufficient. The real problem was the static linking that required too much memory. I switched to dynamic linking. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the linked posts and the comments, I first installed **clang-12** (*the version available for Ubuntu 20.04*) and then used the following configuration:
(*ensure that **build** and **installed** directories exist under project root*)

```bash
user@system:~/llvm-project/build$ cmake -G "Ninja" \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$(which clang) \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$(which clang++) \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld;mlir" \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;RISCV" \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="RelWithDebInfo" \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON \
-DLLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(pwd)/../installed \
-DLLVM_PARALLEL_COMPILE_JOBS=1 \
-DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=1 \
-DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON \
-DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=ON \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
-DLLVM_USE_SPLIT_DWARF=ON \
-DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold \
-DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON \
-DLLVM_USE_NEWPM=ON \
-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS='-Wl,-no-keep-memory,-fuse-ld=gold' \
-DLLVM_CCACHE_BUILD=ON \
../llvm
```

After the configurations are completed, the build is performed via:

```bash
ninja -j1 all
```

The build completed successfully (**took about 2h 10m**). The subsequent **install** operation is completed via:

```bash
ninja install
```

The main objective was to replace static linking of the built libraries with their dynamic linking to prevent the out-of-memory problem. This results in the tools being slower than they should be (*that is to say, the llvm tools resulting from this build will work slower*), but, given hardware constraints, this is the best approach.

---

P.S.

C and C++ compiler path can also be set with:

```bash
env CC=`which clang` CXX=`which clang++` \
```

OR

```bash
CC='/lib/llvm-12/bin/clang' \
CXX='/lib/llvm-12/bin/clang++' \
```

before the cmake command.

`RelWithDebInfo` can be replaced with `Debug`

*If **lld** linker is available:*

`gold` can be replaced with `lld`

`-fuse-ld=gold` can be replaced with `-fuse-ld=lld`

`-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86"` can be replaced with `-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;RISCV"`

Use `-DLLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON` if required.